# How to read data from fetch() getting a ReadableStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Using the fetch-function in a NodeJS application, I receive a response-object that contains a ReadableStream.

In my case, I want to catch errors and I try to figure out any response which could be part of the errornous request.

```
const res = await fetch(url);
if (!res.ok) {
      console.log('Status:', res.status);
      console.log('StatusText:', res.statusText);
      //console.log(res);
      const body = res.body;
      console.log(body);
```

The console.log on the body gives:

```
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
```

How can I use the ReadableStream to get a real string?

I was reading on [Mozilla Database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body) but I don't understand their corresponding article especially not the example, which looks really weird.

Comment: `res.text()` if you want the text or `res.json()` if you want to parse the body as JSON.

Comment: What _is_ the body? Maybe you want the text or json methods.